# TypeError: can't access property "length"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following form:

```
<form name="application" method="POST">
   <div>
     <label>Card Number</label>
     <input name="card_num" type="tel" class="card">
   </div>
   <div>
     <label>Expiry Date</label>
     <input name="expiry" type="tel" class="exp">
   </div>
   <div>
     <label>CVV</label>
     <input name="cvv" type="tel" class="cvv">
   </div>
   <div>
     <button id="submitButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

I am trying to give focus to the submit button when all 3 fields reach their maximum string length:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".card, .exp, .cvv").keyup(function () {
     var card = $('.card');
     var exp = $('.exp');
     var cvv = $('.cvv');
     if (card.value.length == 16 && exp.value.length == 5 && cvv.value.length == 3) {
       $('#submitButton').focus();
     }
  });
});
</script>
```

However I am getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "length", card.value is undefined
```

Comment: `card.value` should be `card.val()`. `value` is a DOM property, `val()` is the analogous jQuery method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use val() instead of value

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".card, .exp, .cvv").keyup(function () {
         var card = $('.card');
         var exp = $('.exp');
         var cvv = $('.cvv');
         if (card.val().length == 16 && exp.val().length == 5 && cvv.val().length == 3) {
           $('#submitButton').focus();
         }
      });
    });
    </script>
```